# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMouseEnter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I would like to build a series of dropdowns that will open when the mouse hovers over them. I'm using React-Bootstrap for the Dropdown. I've defined a function and set it up in my constructor. But it won't render in Chrome, telling me that my onMouseEnter function is undefined.
What am I missing that causes this to happen? I think I'm following the basic React guidelines, but can't figure out what I've missed.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./Menu.css";
import Dropdown from '../../../../../node_modules/react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

class Menu extends Component {  

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen: false
    };

    this.tempData = this.tempData.bind(this);
 } 

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
    }));
  }

  onMouseEnter() {
    this.setState({dropdownOpen: true});
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({dropdownOpen: false});
  }


 tempData(){return ...}


 MakeDropdowns(data) {
    let CreateSubs = function(props){
         let set = props.props;
         let val=[];

         for(var j=0;j<set.length;j++){
            val.push(<Dropdown.Item href={set[j].link} key={set[j].name +" " + j}>{set[j].name}</Dropdown.Item>)
        }

        return val;
    }

    let list = [];
    for(var i=0;i<data.data.length;i++){
        let val = data.data[i];
        list.push(
            <li id="MenuBodyLI" key={val.name+ " " + i}>
                <Dropdown onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave} isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
                  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="secondary" size="sm" id="dropdown-basic">
                  {val.name}
                  </Dropdown.Toggle>
                  <Dropdown.Menu>
                    <CreateSubs props={val.subtitles}/>
                  </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>             
            </li>
        );
    }

    return list;    
  }

  render() {
    const val = this.tempData();

    return (
        <div className="MenuBody">          
            <ul id="MenuBodyUL">
                <this.MakeDropdowns data={val}/>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Menu;

const wrapper = document.getElementById("create-menu");
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, wrapper) : false;
```

Comment: The 10th question in one day about binding... Yep, I count.

Comment: `<Dropdown onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave.bind(this)} isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind your `MakeDropdowns` the same way as e.g. `onMouseEnter`

Also if `MakeDropdowns` is a class method that should create and return JSX elements, you should do it similar like:

```
return (
  <div className="MenuBody">          
    <ul id="MenuBodyUL">
      {this.MakeDropdowns(this.data)} // Do not start your methods with capital letter
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Some example you can find here
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#embedding-map-in-jsx